# Trying to extract from large XML

Tags: xml, bash

Trying to extract information from a very large .dat file which is in an XML format. It was originally the config file for a PRTG setup, but we are trying to transition to Nagios. The problem is we have over 20k sensors and need to port those over by hand or, if possible, by creating a script that can pull the information out. Unfortunately, i'm still very new to bash, and coding in general, and having a hard time getting a successful script to run.

The current script I have is from the wonderful help of Kusalananda from the unix.stackexchange, but the app i'm using is xmlstarlet which is giving a number of issues / errors. I've recorded the errors in the github page [here](https://github.com/keyxmakerx/APIDigital/issues/1). Original script [HERE](https://github.com/keyxmakerx/APIDigital/blob/master/xmlfinder.sh). Hoping someone could help me find a way to extract the information needed out of the .dat file. The example of what is needed is below. The information I need is the host, address, and name.

```
                     <inherited/>
                      </flags>
                      <cell>
                        0
                      </cell>
                    </force32>
                    <host>
                      192.169.1.1
                    </host>
                    <httpproxy>
                      1
                    </httpproxy>
                    <ignoreoverflow>
                      <flags>
                        <inherited/>
                      </flags>
                      <cell>
                        0
                      </cell>
                    </ignoreoverflow>
                    <ignorezero>
                      <flags>
                        <inherited/>
                      </flags>
                      <cell>
```

**Note, the main file is almost 100k lines.

Also was told this information might be helpful.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root version="15" oct="PRTG Network Monitor 17.2.31.1917 x64" 
    saved="5/12/2017 4:36:26 PM" max="184692" guid="{****}" treeversion="0" 
    created="2009-10-02-19-22-11" 
    trial="****">
    <statistics time="12-05-2017 16:09:19">
```

Comment: Upload your xml file somewhere and add link here.

Comment: Issue is that it has private data in it, which is why i can't just share it :/

Comment: Show an example with a [valid xml](https://validator.w3.org/) file.

Comment: This is what I can give as far as an example. When i ran it in the site you sent me, all it could determine it wasn't an HTML file. [Link](https://github.com/keyxmakerx/APIDigital/blob/master/example.txt)

Comment: If the format of the file is the same as the example, you could do `grep -A4 '<host>' file.dat | grep -v 'name\|host'`

Comment: Looks to me as if it might be an encoding issue, i.e. the encoding of the file is not what your (real or improvised) XML parser thinks it is. But you haven't really provided enough evidence for diagnosis.

Comment: in the same direction as @MichaelKay, can verify file encoding `file -i <filename>`, it should be UTF-8 as specified in `<?xml encoding ?>` header

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul you are correct. It outputs "PRTG Configuration(Copy).dat: application/xml; charset=utf-8"